# CollapsingToolbarLayout: How to make a view disappear when collapsed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I used [this](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) tutorial to create a collapsing toolbar to create a layout similar to this:[image].

I want the book thumbnail to disappear when the whole toolbar is collapsed. But somehow, this is what's happening:

[image]

Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.GFSBookContentActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/book_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:tint="@color/gfs_blue" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   <!-- ..... -->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/book_cover_thumb"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried adding a FAB and it disappears. I want that behavior for my image thumbnail. Also, any idea on how to bring the thumbnail image down similar to the image I provided?

Comment: Hey, can you move image view with id "book_cover_thumb" after image view  with id "book_cover".

Answer (score 1):

See the thing is ImageView "**book_cover_thumb**" cannot get scrolled automatically and get disappeared as it do not have any scrolling behavior like FloatingImageButton "**fab**". To make imageview "**book_cover_thumb**" scroll and disappear you have to make a Custom Behavior class and set it to imageview "**book_cover_thumb**".

You can have a reference to this link :
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator